# I have a html page that loaded in div tag in another page using ajax call I want to trigger javascript functions on loaded page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

The main problem is the loaded html page contain loop of cards each card has checkbox I need trigger javascript function that check if checkbox selected then change text value in card to from select to selected, But the function I wrote to trigger this checkboxes not work?
My checkbox tag from the appended html page:

```
<div class="body-action-button u-flex-center">
      <div><input type="checkbox" style="float: left;" name="companies[]" value="<?php echo $company->id; ?>" id="cbtest<?php echo $company->id; ?>" />
        Request an offer</div>
</div>
```

javascript function I used to trigger checkbox :

```
$('.body-action-button').click(function(){
        alert('selected');//This alert for testing
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to give a class to your checkboxes like

```
<input type="checkbox" class="cbxTest" style="float: left;" name="companies[]" value="<?php echo $company->id; ?>" id="cbtest<?php echo $company->id; ?>" />
```

and add your event to JQuery like that:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".cbxTest").click(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            alert("Selected");
        }
    });    
});
```

Also if you want to not trigger it on click but only when checked you can also use `.check` instead of `.click` like that

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".cbxTest").change(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            alert("Selected");
        }
    });    
});
```

Both works well. It's just about the scenerio...

Answer (score 0):

Try this ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dm3f7src/1/)):
JS

```
$('input:checkbox[name=example]').each(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    alert("selected");
  }
  // else {}
});
```

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="example" /> label one
<input type="checkbox" name="example" checked/> label two
```